# MVC - Clear default selected value of SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a SelectList that gets populated with data from the database. The data comes from a `Dictionary<int, string>` and populates the SelectList like below.

```
//...

Courses = new SelectList(GetCourses(),"Key","Value");

//...
```

On the View, it shows the first record from the database as the default selected value on the dropdown. I'd like to clear this value and leave the dropdown empty so the user can manually select a value. If possible without using javascript.

```
//I have this on the view
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseID, Model.Courses) %>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [the overload which takes an optionLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx):

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseID, Model.Courses, string.Empty) %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course, so obvious. I guess its time to quit and take my uncle up on that bartender job.

Comment: also, See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx