# Adding empty string to selectList as SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm populating `DropdownList`  with data retrieved from database. I want to add default empty string. I'm trying with `SelectedValue property` with no effects. I tried already `null` and `string.empty` like in sample below

```
ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(unitOfWork.projectRepository.Get(), "ProjectName", "ProjectName",string.Empty);
```

DropDownList declaration in View

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Project", null, new { @class="form-control"})
```

which translates into:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Project" name="Project">
    <option value="Sample project">Sample project</option>
    <option value="Second project">Second project</option>
</select>
```

By there is no option with String.Empty.

What should I change in my code

As @Alexander suggested I converted it with ToList  and now this is my code:

```
var items = unitOfWork.projectRepository.Get();
items=items.ToList<Project>().Insert(0, new Project { ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "" });
ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(items, "ProjectName", "ProjectName",string.Empty);
```

but this throws exception:`Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<magazyn.Models.Project>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC - Clear default selected value of SelectList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780614/mvc-clear-default-selected-value-of-selectlist)

Comment: In the amendment, break your second line of code into two; you're trying to assign the result of Insert() to items - Insert() doesn't return a value (is void). Do the ToList on the same line as the Get to change the type of items at declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectList` contains no overloads that accept an empty default option. You can add it to your items collection manually:

```
var items = unitOfWork.projectRepository.Get();
items.Insert(0, new Item {ProjectId = null, ProjectName == "", });

ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(items, "ProjectName", "ProjectName",string.Empty);
```

**Update**

About the additional convert exception: You are trying to assign the result of the `Insert` function to a `List`. Use this code:

```
var items = unitOfWork.projectRepository.Get().ToList();
items.Insert(0, new Project { ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "" });
```

Comment: Look promising. Now I only need to find how to insert something into my `IEnumerable` items collection

Comment: Just convert it `ToList`, and call `Insert`.